# Alternating v-for DOM elements on same level

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I am trying to have two alternating loops after each other on the same level. If I wrap it in a parent element and loop thru it brakes the styles.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
<div v-for="category in items" class="cat-name">{{ category.name }}</div>
<div v-for="category in items" class="cat-meta">{{ category.metaData }}</div>
```

Wanted Result:

```
<div class="cat-name">name1</div>
<div class="cat-meta">metadata1</div>
<div class="cat-name">name2</div>
<div class="cat-meta">metadata2</div>
<div class="cat-name">name3</div>
<div class="cat-meta">metadata3</div>
```

and so on...

I really hope that this is possible since it completely breaks the styles when I tried:

```
<div v-for="category in items">
    <div class="cat-name">{{ category.name }}</div>
    <div class="cat-meta">{{ category.metaData }}</div>
</div>
```

Really appreciate any help and input.
Thanks, -J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap both your elements in a [template tag](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt).
Unlike a basic tag, this one will not be rendered in the DOM.

```vue
<template v-for="category in items">
    <div class="cat-name">{{ category.name }}</div>
    <div class="cat-meta">{{ category.metaData }}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: WOW! Awesome you solved my issue in less than 5 minutes of posting it. You are the best! Thanks a lot!